# Create Anti-Phase / Inverse sound / noise cancel with audio byte data

Tags: java, audio, bit-manipulation, buffer

I am trying to check if it is possible to create Anti-noise or sound inverse using Java. ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_noise_control))

I used the following format:

```
AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 16000, 16, 2, 4, 16000, false);
```

Once I captured a recording, I plan to use java's SourceDataLine class to write the stream out. Playing works normally. however as the goal is to "invert" the sound, I have to change the direction to it's opposite value (which as I have read so far is done by multiplying the value of the value  by -1)

Since we use 16bit format, each 2 bytes in the stream counts as one value.

```
for(int i = 0; i < readBytes; i+=2)
{
    inverse = (short)(data[i+1] << 8 | data[i] & 0xff);
    System.out.println(inverse/100);
    data[i] = (byte) (inverse & 0xff); 
    data[i+1] = (byte) ((inverse >> 8) & 0xff); 
}
```

The code above reads each 2bytes, convert them into a 16bit short, reverse its value then insert it back to the same byte positions.

However, when this is runs,it sounds exactly like the original.

```
sourceLine.write(data, 0, readBytes);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the sound is the same, only with pressure value reversed.
Your ear measures the absolute value of the pressure wave, that is the same for a reversed wave. 
Only when the wave and the reversed one are playing together their sum is 0, and only if played perfectly synchronized.

Comment: hmm if that's the case then is that because the time it converts is slow in java. the audio has like half a second lag from source of sound. is this even possible to produce in java technology or java is too slow for processing things like these.

Answer (score 1):

If a stream of samples is, `X0.....Xn`, it's inverse (or anti phase, if you prefer) is `-X0.....-Xn`.

Simply negating the `inverse` will do the trick:

```
   inverse = -((short)(data[i+1] << 8 | data[i] & 0xff));
```

The inverted audio will, of course, sound precisely like the original in absence of phase cancellation in free space.